# Calculating Perplexity

Tags: information-theory, natural-language

In the Coursera NLP course , Dan Jurafsky calculates the following perplexity:

Operator(1 in 4)
Sales(1 in 4)
Technical Support(1 in 4)
30,000 names(1 in 120,000 each)
He says the Perplexity is 53.

The lecture can be found here: https://youtu.be/b6nwdc_fGfA @ 8:40.

I've been trying to figure out how it's calculated but I just can't get it. I've tried to switch to log's because of the 1/120000 but I still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: this perplexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity ?

Comment: Yes, but the equation used by Jurafsky is P(w1, w2, ..., wN)^-(1/N)

Comment: so if all things are equal in likelihood then the probability of any outcome is the frequency of that outcome divided by the frequency of all possible outcomes.  4*4*30k = 480k alternatives.  The likelihood of any one outcome is one in 480k.  That should plug into your expression yielding perplexity.

Comment: why only 2 4's?

Comment: link no longer available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon this searching how perplexity is calculated. I think applying the Jurafsky formula I find the right number (I used R):

```
P1 <- 1/4
P2 <- 1/4
P3 <- 1/4
P4 <- 1/120000

SP <- P1*P2*P3*P4
Result <- SP**(-1/4)
```

Result is 52.64296

Comment: The formula is given by $P(w_1, \ldots, w_n)^{-(1/N)}$. Why did you choose $N = 4$ when there are 30000 names? Shouldn't $N = 30003$, where you have 3 for "operator", "sales", and "technical support" and then 30000 for the names?

Comment: each name has the same probability, although there are 30000 names

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted the probabilities here as:
Let's imagine there are 120000 words in total, where by probability distribution:

Operator, Sales and Technical Support each occur 30,000 times (P = 1/4)

Each of the name occur only once (P = 1/120000).

Perplexity can be calculated then, using the formula: 
$(\frac{1}{4}^{30000} * \frac{1}{4}^{30000} * \frac{1}{4}^{30000} * \frac{1}{120000}^{30000}) ^ \frac{-1}{120000}$